# Python MapReduce on Sun Grid Engine

Tags: python, mapreduce, distributed-computing, sungridengine

I am relatively new to distributed computing, so forgive me if I misunderstand some of the basic concepts here.  I am looking for a (preferably) Python-based alternative to Hadoop for processing large data sets via MapReduce on a cluster using an SGE-based grid engine (eg. OpenGrid or Sun of Grid Engine).  I have had good luck running basic distributed jobs with [PythonGrid](http://code.google.com/p/pythongrid/), but I'd really like a more feature-rich framework for running my jobs.  I have read up on tools like [Disco](http://discoproject.org/) and [MinceMeatPy](https://github.com/michaelfairley/mincemeatpy), both of which seem to offer true Map-Sort-Reduce job processing, but their does not seem to be any obvious support for SGE.  This makes me wonder if it is possible to achieve true MapReduce functionality using a grid scheduler, or if people just don't support it out-of-the-box because they are not frequently used.  Can you perform Map-Sort-Reduce tasks on a grid engine?  Are their Python tools that support this?  How difficult would it be to rig existing MapReduce tools to use SGE job schedulers?

Answer (score 2):

I've heard that [Jug](http://jug.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#will-jug-work-on-batch-cluster-systems-like-sge-or-pbs) works. It's using the filesystem for coordination amongst the parallel tasks. In that kind of framework, you'd write your code and run "jug status primes.py" on the machine you're on then start a grid array job with as many workers as you like, all running "jug execute primes.py".

mincemeat.py should be able to function in the same way but looks to use the network for coordination. So that may depend on whether your nodes can talk to a server running the overall script.

There are several release notes about running actual [Hadoop MapReduce and HDFS on SGE](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/howto/GridEngineHadoop.html), but I haven't been able to find good documentation.

If you're used to [Hadoop streaming with Python](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/), it's not too bad to replicate on SGE.  I've had some success with this at work: I run an array job that does map + shuffle for each input file. Then another array job that does sort + reduce for each reducer number. The shuffle part just writes files to a network dir like mapper00000_reducer00000, mapper00000_reducer00001, and so on (all pairs of mapper and reducer numbers). Then reducer 00001 sorts all files labeled reducer00001 together and pipes to reducer code.

Unfortunately, Hadoop streaming isn't very full-featured.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it has given me something to think about.  I'm curious how your solution performs reading/writing so many intermediary files.  Ever tried using a database like Cassandra instead of writing to files?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Cassandra. From reading though their slides, I doubt I could use it; it seems like it needs dedicated Cassandra boxes. But at a high level, I don't know that it would speed things up unless I had a lot of Cassandra nodes. Doing map-reduce on SGE is entirely sequential reads/writes so I wouldn't use the random-access aspect of Cassandra. So Cassandra would help if I could do an installation with enough disk parallelism to provide high bandwidth than a networked filesystem.